# i2cdetect shows all blanks or UU

Tags: i2c

I am facing a difficulty using MCP23017 with raspberry pi (stratodesk OS). I would like to know if I missed any configuration to get MCP23017 working

my config.txt file:

```
dtparam=i2c1=on, dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay -h i2c-bcm2708, sda1_pin=2, scl1_pin=3
dtoverlay mcp23017.dtbo
dtoverlay mcp23017
```

bash:

```
modprobe i2c-dev
```

i2cdetect -y 1

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

now if I change the address to 0x21 A0=1, A1=0, A2=0 and reboot. i2cdetect shows all blanks even if I specify the address in config.txt as `dtoverlay mcp23017,addr=0x21`

Comment: What do you mean by all zeros?  If you mean the above that is correct behaviour for a device which is meant to be connected to address 0x20 and is known to the kernel.  If it doesn't show up when moved to 0x21 then **your wiring is wrong**.  Please add a clear photo showing the connections between the Pi and the chip.

Comment: @joan thanks. zeros mean no addresses appear. Yes, when moving to 0x21 does not show up. the wire is correct as connecting to Raspian OS the connections were working correctly.

Comment: @joan zeros = blanks (already correct it)

Comment: If you need to modprobe you are running an obsolete distribution.  Contact the author of that distribution for support.

Comment: frankly I don't care about what command to use. I only need to get my project working :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what (if anything) the stuff you used will do.

I would just use the Device Tree overlay as documented in `/boot/overlays/README` `dtoverlay=mcp23017`

If you NEED to to use a different address add the `addr` parameter.

**Don't** modprobe ANYTHING - this is obsolete

```
Name:   mcp23017
Info:   Configures the MCP23017 I2C GPIO expander
Load:   dtoverlay=mcp23017,<param>=<val>
Params: gpiopin                 Gpio pin connected to the INTA output of the
                                MCP23017 (default: 4)

        addr                    I2C address of the MCP23017 (default: 0x20)

        mcp23008                Configure an MCP23008 instead.
```

Comment: "Don't modprobe ANYTHING - this is obsolete" but without modprobe, `i2cdetect` is not working showing this error `i2cdetect: can't open '/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory`

Comment: @AbdulkarimKanaan Correctly used Device Tree does ALL that is needed! modprobe is pre Device Tree!

Comment: so I can assume `dtoverlay=mcp23017` is not working in my case?

Comment: what do you mean by `mcp23008                Configure an MCP23008 instead.`?

Comment: using only `dtoverlay=mcp23017` without `modprobe`, i2cdetect still shows `i2cdetect: can't open '/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory`. any idea?

Comment: a question please, I add this `dtoverlay=mcp23017` inside config.txt, right?

Comment: @AbdulkarimKanaan Yes - read the documented in `/boot/overlays/README`

Comment: ok, thanks. unfortunately there is no such path on Stratodesk OS :(